# How to Fix This "system.nullreferenceexception object reference not set to an instance of an object" in mvc web service

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api, devexpress

**In My Controller**

```
public string Post(Order od)
        {

            string result = "";

            Database newDB= new Database("New");
            try
            {

              newDB.Execute(@"insert into TABLE_A(BranchID,CustomerName,BirthDate,BirthPlace) 
                Select @0,@1,@2,@3",
                new object[] {od.BranchID,od.CustomerName,od.BirthDate,od.BirthPlace});


                newDB.CloseSharedConnection();
                result = "succes";
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                result = Ex.Message;

            }

            return result;
        }
```

in error message

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object"

I try created a new object odr:

```
public string Post(Order od)
        {

            string result = "";
            Order odr = new Order();
            Database newDB= new Database("New");
            try
            {

              Log.Info("REQ:" + od.BranchID + "|" + od.CustomerName + "|" + od.BirthDate + "|" + od.BirthPlace);
              newDB.Execute(@"insert into TABLE_A(BranchID,CustomerName,BirthDate,BirthPlace) 
                Select @0,@1,@2,@3",
                new object[] {odr.BranchID,odr.CustomerName,odr.BirthDate,odr.BirthPlace});


                newDB.CloseSharedConnection();
                result = "succes";
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                result = Ex.Message;
                Log.Error(Ex)             
            }

            return result;
        }
```

but the data that I've post is null. Please help my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

NullRefException is one of the basic programming error you should learn and avoid. How did you set collectionDB? Or if it's not collectionDB was null, just share exception stacktrace here so we will see and help you point out the cause of this.

Besides, never catch the top-level Exception like this. Catching exception without logging is a bad practice in all cases.

Comment: Im sorry i forgot change collectionDB to newDB, I add a log to determine whether the input data that I entered are inserted to db , but the data is unreadable the value is null

Comment: `Order odr = new Order();` That's the point. Why aren't you using the order passed to your function as parameter instead of creating a complete new empty order object?

Comment: thats the problem when i'm not create new empty object and use the parameter this message's shown "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Ok so you should go up to check if the caller of method Post passing a null Order parameter to the function. Call Stack is a very useful feature of VS for you in this case.